# use ipywidget interactive() with option manual=True

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

I am updating a jupyter notebooks with interactive widgets to a more recent version (ipywidgets 7.2.1).

It used to have `interactive()` functions that were executed manually by clicking on a button (feature `__manual=True`). However now I cannot reproduce the same behavior.

Here is a minimal example:

```
from ipywidgets import interactive, interact_manual
import ipywidgets as widgets

def do_sth(x):
    #do sth with the argument passed
    print("done "+str(x))

nb = widgets.BoundedIntText(description='Number:')

#Interaction in accordion nested in a tab
tab = widgets.Tab()
tab.set_title(0, 'Page 1')

#old method 
#problem: it is not manual anymore
w = interactive(do_sth, x=nb, __manual=True)

#new solution 1
#problem: the widget appears also outside the tab/accordion
w1 = interact_manual(do_sth, x=nb)
w1.widget.children[1].description = 'do sth' #seems a bit of a hack

#new solution 2
w2 = interactive(do_sth, x=nb, manual=True) #does no pass the manual option
#if I set it manually with:
#w2.manual = True 
#It generates an error (AttributeError: 'interactive' object has no attribute 'manual_button')

accordion = widgets.Accordion(children=[w, w1.widget, w2])
accordion.set_title(0, 'old interaction 0')
accordion.set_title(1, 'new interaction 1')
accordion.set_title(2, 'new interaction 2')

tab.children = [accordion]

tab
```

Is it possible to use solution 1 and prevent the widget from appearing twice? Otherwise, is there another way to do this?

Comment: If I understand, you want an interact_manual that does not automatically display the widget when it is created?

Comment: @ac24 Yes, exactly!

Comment: I had a look through the code for interacts but I couldn't easily find a combination that gives you what you like. Have you considered posting as an issue on github? https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems they may have moved it into a dict when adding the ability to relabel the button.

Try

`w2 = interactive(do_sth, {'manual' : True, 'manual_name' : 'Do Something'}, x=nb)`